# Equation of circle - Third point?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Suppose $f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the circle such that  $f(x,1)=0$ has equal roots (each equal to $2$) and $f(1,x)=0$ also has equal roots (each equal to $0$).
Find the equation of the circle.

My attempt:
I could only gather that the circle meets the lines $x=1$ and $y=1$ at $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ respectively.

Comment: The lines are also tangent lines for the circle (equal roots).

Comment: How should I use it?

Answer (score 3):

The condition that $f(1,y)=0$ has a double root at $y=0$ means that the line $x=1$ has one point intersection with the circle at $(1,0)$, which is possible only when the line is tangent and $(1,0)$ is the tangent point. Similarly for the second condition. Now, can you think of a circle that touches two lines at the given points?

[image]

Here is the spoiler:

> [image]
> $$(x-2)^2+y^2-1=0.$$

Comment: So the circle is (x-1)(x-2)+(y)(y-1)=0

Comment: @AmitHegde Not really. Try to draw the circle. Where should the center be?

Comment: Ok I understand all other circles intersect the two lines at more points. Thank you!